# Using Browser to visit a url

Tags: google-chrome, curl

From curl command, I way run something as

```
curl --interface 123.45.67.89 www.facebook.com,
```

which is to visit www.facebook.com, starting by this address "123.45.67.89".  How may I do the similar work if I was using a chrome browser ?

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your OS, use your [hosts file](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/):

```
123.45.67.89 www.facebook.com
```

Then when you visit the URL in your browser, it will point to that IP address.